# backslash in macro name

Tags: macros, tex-core, definition

Very simple code:

```
\def\a{12}
\def\a\b{34}
\a\b        % ok: 34
\a          % error
\bye
```

Very simple question: I would like to know how `\def\a\b{34}` is processed by the tex engine and why `\a` no longer works:

```
! Use of \a doesn't match its definition.
```

Comment: You can read something about TeX tokenization process and macro definitions. In short: none in TeX is character string. TeX works only with token strings. Look at TeX in nutshell, for example https://ctan.org/pkg/tex-nutshell?lang=en

Comment: @wipet Nice. Easy to read. Thank you for writing this great material.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're defining `\a` twice. By rule, the second definition overrides the first one.

The second definition is of a macro with name `\a` and *parameter text* `\b`. By rule, this *exact* token is required to follow each call of `\a`.

Thus `\a\b` will expand to the replacement text, namely `34`. The call `\a` will result in an error, because the lookup for `\b` fails. You can notice that the message is about `\a` not matching its definition.

According to the rules of the tokenization process, `\a\b` is *two* tokens, not one. You cannot define a macro with a backslash in its name unless you use `\csname...\endcsname` or change the category code (but then you will not be able to use `\` for prefixing command names).

You can check the TeXbook or TeX by Topic looking for “delimited argument” and “parameter text”.

---

By the way, LaTeX uses macros with a backslash in their name all the time. A declaration such as

```
\newcommand{\foo}[2][default]{#1--#2}
```

will define `\foo` and also `\\foo`, although the latter macro is not available to the end user, unless the input `\csname\string\foo\endcsname` is used. The first is a “real” backslash, the second one is a character, part of the token's name.

Comment: Interesting. I'm running plain tex not latex, but I can do `\def\\a{12}` then `\\a` outputs `12`. Does this mean this macro name is `\a` and so backslash is a valid character in macro names? Are there any forbidden characters for macro names?

Comment: @Cyker The macro name is ``\\`` with parameter text `a`.

Comment: Then how about "\\\", "\\\\"...? And macro name in another example: `\def\a\a{34}`? Both macro name and parameter text are `\a`?

Comment: @Cyker You cannot do `\def\\\{...}` (try it). If you do `\def\a\a{34}`, then the macro name is `\a` with parameter text `\a`.

Comment: I can't do 3 backslashes but 4 is OK. Odd is error but even is OK. I guess there's some escape issue.

Comment: Btw, parameter text is always a string not a token? When I write `\def\a\a{34}` then use it with `\a\a`, the second `\a` is seen as string but not a token to be expanded?

Comment: @Cyker With `\def\\\{12}` TeX will start absorbing the definition of ``\\`` with parameter text `\{12`, but will find the `}` and issue an error, because a `{` has not been found yet. About “strings” and “tokens”, TeX only has tokens.

Comment: Alright, got the idea. TYVM